# System.BadImageFormatException on oracle connection string

Tags: c#, oracle

I am getting a `System.BadImageFormatException` exception when I try to connect to Oracle. This string worked 4 years ago, but now it is not. What am I doing wrong?

```
string conn = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hosturl)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DEV)));User Id=username; Password=password;";
```

Comment: It's not the connection string that's the problem. `BadImageFormatException` means you have an architecture mismatch (usually 32-bit vs. 64-bit) between your application and the native library used by the Oracle ADO.NET provider. Something in your project changed. Maybe it was running as 32-bit and it got redeployed wrong and is 64-bit now? Assuming, it's a web application, check the AppPool.

Comment: thank you. I will.

Comment: I think that it was using System.Data.OracleClient that caused the progblem.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!